# decoding binary data as MIPS instructions

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am having trouble figuring out what these two MIPS instructions would be.

```
0b1000_1111_1110_1111_1100_0000_0000_0000
0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000
```

Is there a way to use MARS IDE to figure out what these instructions are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a LW (load word into register) and the seconds is a NOOP (no operation) which is actually a shift register $0 0 steps and store in register $0.

See [wiki of MIPS instructionset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_I_instruction_formats).

Comment: Wouldn't trying to store something in register $0 produce some sort of error?

Comment: @russjohnson09 Not an error as I understand it, but nothing would be stored in the register.

Comment: Storing the result to $0 is a useful way of converting many MIPS instructions to no-ops. Being able to do this can help when patching existing code.